# Reading data from a table does not work in particular table

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am currently trying to create a new PPT presentation by deleting unwanted slides from a presentation. The slides - and their slide numbers - are being selected in the first column of a table I have in Excel.

I tried to solve this problem by taking another table instead of the one I want to use and it worked. For some reason it seems not work with the "Table 3".

```
Sub CreatingNewPresentation()

Dim Destination1PPT As String
Dim ppApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim TempArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

If MsgBox("This can take a while", vbOKCancel + vbExclamation, "Creating new presentation") = vbCancel Then

Exit Sub

Else
    Set ppApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
        Destination1PPT = "C:\Users\Steffen\Desktop\Test2\1.pptx"
    Set ppPres = ppApp.Presentations.Open(Destination1PPT)
        ppApp.Visible = True
        ppApp.Activate
    Set myTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table3")
        TempArray = myTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

    For x = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count To 1 Step -1

        If IsError(Application.Match(x, TempArray, False)) Then

                 ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Delete

        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

I expect the code to open the presentation and delete all slides except the ones I store in "Table3" - column 1. 
What it does instead is just open the presentation and nothing else. There is no error message.

Comment: I would assume (though you should verify by stepping through the code) that the `If IsError` - statement is constantly resulting in False. Also, for `Application.Match`, isn't the third argument supposed to be one of: (-1,0,1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the "stupid" mistake I made. I was getting ALL data entries of the referred table instead only getting the visible data entries.

This helps:

```
 Set myTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table3")
 TempArray = myTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```